# how to change 'isLiked' value in like button depends on database

Tags: flutter, dart

in database i save all 'id_user' who liked the post. so, later i can check it if user already liked the post or not. i store user id into the list, i check it by using contains method into the list like this

```
storyList[index]['id_user_liked'].toString().Contains(userId);
```

by using that i wish i can check the user id. by using like button we need 'isliked' parameter. how to make the parameter 'isliked' match the value of the code containing the list above. so, if the user id likes a post in the list, the like button will be red whenever i reopen the app.
here my likes button code inside the listview:

```
LikeButton(
                                                      size: 20,
                                                      likeCount: int.parse(
                                                          storyList[index]
                                                              ['postLike']),
                                                      countPostion:
                                                          CountPostion.right,
                                                      likeBuilder: (isLiked) {
                                                        return Icon(
                                                          Icons.favorite,
                                                          color: isLiked
                                                              ? Colors.red
                                                              : Colors.grey,
                                                          size: 20,
                                                        );
                                                      },
                                                  
                                                      countBuilder: (likeCount,
                                                          isLiked, text) {
                                                        return Text(
                                                          likeCount == 0
                                                              ? "0"
                                                              : text,
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              color: isLiked
                                                                  ? Colors.red
                                                                  : Colors.grey,
                                                              fontSize: 12),
                                                        );
                                                      },
                                                    ),
```

Comment: What service do you use for database?

Comment: i use mysql and php.

Comment: and how do you get data from database?

Comment: im usign php to get the data form the database and i store the data in list.

Comment: Do you use anything for state management?

Comment: no i don't use it.